# Keyboard layout switching with synergy

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, keyboard-layout, synergy

I'm using Synergy server on my Ubuntu machine and using a Windows 7 machine as client. On my Ubuntu machine I have mapped so that pressing the Pause button switches between US and Swedish keyboard layouts. However, when mouse/keyboard is on the Windows machine, pressing Pause has no effect. Is there a way to instruct Synergy on the Windows client to pass through the proper hotkey to the server?

Answer (score -1):

You can switch keyboard layout in windows 7, install the new layout (I don t remember how to right now), and in the toolbar you can configure multiple layout.

EDIT:

In the toolbar, you have a "language" tool, just look in the parameters. I have French and English UK side by side, note that it will (in some software) also change the language detection).

You can assign hotkeys in the parameters for each languages.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work. The layout has to be switched on the server, or the mapping will not be correct. (At least not in my case.) Switching on the client will only affect input from the client's own keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I thought Synergy was some vm manager tool, not a keyboard manager. Maybe Pause is 'eated' by Windows, so you need to use another hotkey?

Comment: Perhaps, but I've yet to find a hotkey which is not eaten. Synergy will (and should) by default eat all keystrokes, so I suspect that I need to instruct Synergy to explicitly pass certain keystrokes back to the server.